# Is there a way to "force" a visit?

Tags: cypress, onload

I'm using the `cy.visit()` command but the website i'm visiting (which i don't own) doesn't always fire the `load` event, although the content itself that i need for testing does appear on the website.

Despite the content appearing, since the `load` event is not fired sometimes (for some reason which i can't fix since i don't have ownership over this website), the `cy.visit()` command fails.

Is there a way to "force" it somehow, similar to how we can pass `{ force: true}` for the `cy.click()` command?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below to your cypress commands file

```
Cypress.Commands.add('forceVisit', url => {
    cy.window().then(win => {
        return win.open(url, '_self'); 
      });
});
```

And in your tests, you can call

```
cy.forceVisit("www.google.com")
```

Comment: That also didn't work :(

Comment: The comment like that really isn't helpful, provide an error, or explanation. How do you expect to get a help like that?

Comment: This is the only way to force visit

Comment: Hi @Gambit2007, did you set chromeWebSecurity to false in your config? Here's a reference to this answer: https://medium.com/@lasithdilshan20/cypress-force-visit-to-a-different-origin-321c2c356702

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to simulate the problem, but I think I managed by setting `pageLoadTimeout` really low (30ms).

You can catch the onLoad fail in an event handler and checking for the page load error message.

I recommend doing it in a beforeEach().

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  Cypress.config("pageLoadTimeout", 30)  // set this to whatever time length
                                         // you feel is appropriate to start testing
                                         // You'll need to experiment to get this right
                                         // and in CI it will be a lot longer

  cy.once('fail', (err) => {             // "once" to just catch a single error

    const message = err.parsedStack[0].message
    if (message.match(/Timed out after waiting `\d+ms` for your remote page to load/)) {
      return false
    }

    throw err                            // any other error, fail it
  })

  cy.visit('www.example.com');
})

it('checks the heading of the page', () => {

  cy.get('h1').should('have.text', 'Example Domain')    // ✅
 
})
```

[image]

Comment: This will make sure the test doesn't fail, but Cypress still won't "move on" to the next command after `.visit()` if the `load` event isn't fired.

Comment: My test functions just fine after bypassing the page load event. What are you doing wrong?

Comment: It would be more helpful to have an proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As you can already assume, that is highly **discouraged**. It also really depends on how it fails and with which errors, but, without any code to reproduce, you may want to try this if you haven't already:

```
cy.visit('/', {failOnStatusCode: false});
```

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Arguments

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help :(